# Batch file error: "xcopy is not recognized as an internal or external command..."

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, xcopy

I'm programming a batch file and after a long amount of code, I have:

```
:d1copy
xcopy /Y "C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\JOKO_Sync\*.*" "F:\JOKO_Sync\*.*" /s /e /V /D
pause
```

When I execute this, I get the error

**xcopy is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

Yet I copy and paste this same code into another batch file, and it works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your `Path` environment variable include `C:\Windows\System32`!

Comment: Thanks for the response. It does not.  Can I put a line in that just says "C:\Windows\System32 !" to fix that error?

Comment: @JSUPRA Yes, you can do that, just don't forget the smicolon before

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't needed to do that before.  So if I understand, it would be:

:d1copy
C:\Windows\System32! 
xcopy /Y "C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\JOKO_Sync\*.*" "F:\JOKO_Sync\*.*" /s /e /V /D
pause

Comment: @JSUPRA-No,those are the contents of batch file, you should simply add the path of system32 in your Path environment variable

Comment: `set Path=%path%;C:\Windows\system32` this command will add C:\Windows\system32 folder to the `%path%` then xcopy will work

Comment: If the same code work inside another batch file, the problem is the batch file, not the xcopy command. Are you using/changing the `path` variable inside this batch?

Comment: MC ND's question is the likely reason for it failing.  Just repeating here that you are probably using a variable called `path`

Comment: I used 'xcopy /-y' and it show same error while I could physically find xcopy.exe in my system32 folder. But when I remove '/-y' it worked. So try to use 'xcopy' without options.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your `Path` environment variable doesn't contain `C:\Windows\System32`. Please try adding it and your error will be resolved!

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  This is what I'm running now:
:d1copy

xcopy /Y "C:\Windows\System32\Users\Joseph\Desktop\JOKO_Sync\*.*" "F:\JOKO_Sync\*.*" /s /e /V /D
pause

Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Did you add `System32` location into `Path` as it contains all the executables.

Comment: No I haven't.  Do you write a line of code to do that?

Comment: My file path on x copy now reads
"C:\Windows\System32\Users\Joseph\Desktop\JOKO_Sync\*.*"
But it's not working, so Im guessing I need to add System32 to the path in a different way

Comment: Whatever contents are right now added to your `Path` variable,you just leave it unchanged! Just append `C:\Windows\System32` this to the end if there is a semi-colon`(;)` at the end! If it ain't, then append this--->`;C:\Windows\System32\`. Please don't delete the contents! SImply append at last....

Comment: Have you added upto `JOKO` in your Path environment variable??? If yes,don't!!! Please remove that! If not,then kindly add as hinted in the above comment...

Comment: Thanks for your continued help.  Here is what I have tried:
xcopy /Y "C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\JOKO_Sync\C:\Windows\System32;" "F:\JOKO_Sync\*.*" /s /e /V /D

xcopy /Y "C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\JOKO_Sync\" "F:\JOKO_Sync\*.*" /s /e /V /D C:\Windows\System32;

Comment: Has any of those lines I have posted come close to what you are talking about?

Comment: probably not. why are you adding the system32 path to the file ypu want to copy, instead to xcopy?

Comment: Got it.  It's coming up with a different error now, so it solved the problem.  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Well you really helped me out and I appreciate it. Thanks again

Comment: @JSUPRA-Glad to help you. Good luck for your project!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you may have defined set path= to something in your batch file. So it'll change your current system path variable. If so change your batch file variable name different to "path" (ex: mypath) and it will work.

Comment: three and a half year too late, but the first correct answer. By analyzing the comments, OP did in fact set `path` to his source folder

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting the `PATH` variable (which could then still break if you moved the script to another machine), you could simply [specify the full path to `xcopy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273427/xcopy-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or/17679169#17679169):

```
%systemroot%\System32\xcopy ...
```

so in your case:

```
%systemroot%\System32\xcopy /Y "C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\JOKO_Sync\*.*" "F:\JOKO_Sync\*.*" /s /e /V /D
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying `xcopy.exe` file from `C:/Windows/System32` to `JAVA_SDK/bin` worked for me.