# Deploy a Java app on FX7500 RFID reader

Tags: rfid, reader

I have developed a Java program using eclipse provided by Motorola. The program runs well in windows.

In that particular eclipse, there is a tool for application package builder, which will build a .deb file to be installed in FX7500 RFID reader.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eidyU.jpg)

When I try to use that builder, the command prompt asks me for a few input, one of them is files directory. I input my jar file directory, and there is an error "Invalid file path".
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYmsq.jpg)

What should I input then?

I view the log, it is due to xcopy.
*

```
--> Running 'FX7500 Embedded SDK App Package Builder' (Mon 13/03/2017- 9:47:27.38) ... 
---> User input ... 
---> Clean up ... 
The system cannot find the file specified.
---> Creating folders ... 
---> Creating 'debian-binary' file ... 
---> Creating 'control' file ... 
---> Adding files into 'data' folder ... 
'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
---> ERROR - Invalid file path
```

- Anyone knows the correct way?

Comment: It is better if you can add your piece of code, which cause this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the packaging tool can't find the xcopy program on your machine. You might need to [configure your path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273427/xcopy-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or).